# How to set up orientation and margins for a PDF layout in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layouts

My PyQGIS code is exporting the map canvas (plus some other stuff) to a PDF file. The problem is when I try to tailor the PDF layout. I can choose between paper sizes (e.g. letter or A4) without any problem, but switching to a portrait layout or setting margins do not work properly.

For example, changing the paper orientation to portrait uses the following snippet:

```
self.layout_pdf = QgsPrintLayout(self.project)
self.papyrus = QgsLayoutItemPage(self.layout_pdf)
if self.ori == 'Landscape':
    self.papyrus.setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)
    self.x_L = 297.0
    self.y_L = 210.0
elif self.ori == 'Portrait':
    self.papyrus.setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Portrait)
    self.x_L = 210.0
    self.y_L = 297.0
```

This works well when the orientation is landscape as the screenshot shows

[image]

However, and when the orientation is portrait, it switches the map canvas orientation but not the orientation of the paper itself, which remains landscape as shown in the screenshot. [Note: I also tried `self.layout_pdf.setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Portrait)` but got the error `AttributeError: 'QgsPrintLayout' object has no attribute 'setPageSize'` as expected]

[image]

As for adding a margin, I thought that QgsMargins might help, but the line
`self.papyrus.resizeToContents(QgsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20),QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)` returns `AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutItemPage' object has no attribute 'resizeToContents'` I'm not sure whether to use QgsMargins or attack the problem using a different tool.
P.S. I'm using QGIS 3.30

Comment: Looks like you're doing everything according to the rules. Could this be some version-specific bug? Could you try the same in the latest LTR version? 3.28 iirc.

Comment: I haven't seen your comment until a few minutes ago. Actually I was going to try to upgrade to v3.32 next week in order to start using KEA format (this is unrelated to the current post) but my point is that I might have to try different configurations and check out what works and what doesn't. Downgrading to v3.28 would be the last resource but I'll let you know if I notice any improvement with different versions.

Comment: Good luck with that. Please, do let me know. This one really piqued my curiosity.